# How does JavaScript compare Date strings?

Tags: javascript, date, string-comparison

When comparing two strings, like so:

```
'03-15-2019' < '03-16-2019'
```

I get a value of `true`, which is what I expect.

I'm curious to learn a little more about how this works though. Is this doing a comparison of two dates, or is there some other comparison going on that I don't quite see?

Comment: string comparison

Comment: It's just comparing strings, not dates.  Change the year of the second date to 2015.  The comparison result will be the same.

Comment: It's a pure string comparison. `'5'.charCodeAt()` is lower than `'6'.charCodeAt()`

Comment: Those are not Date strings as far as JavaScript is concerned, just a jumble of alpha-numeric characters, so there is no chance of any "type-coercion" which is the proper name for what you are suggesting.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date strings are just strings so they obey javascript string comparison rules.

```
console.log('04-13-2019' < '04-15-2019') #true
```

But be careful here because if you rely on this comparison because if the two strings are not of the same length, it will result in unexpected behaviors like this:

```
console.log('ab' < 'b') #true
```

If you want to compare dates, you would better rely on `Date` object or use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

String comparison happens character by character

```js
console.log('aaaa' < 'b')
console.log('aa' < 'ab')
console.log('ab' < 'aa')
```

`'03-15-2019' < '03-16-2019'` This is just string comparison not date comparison, if you want to compare dates you need to change it to date Object and than compare

```js
console.log(new Date('03/15/2019') < new Date('03/16/2019'))
```